# jquery window resize error when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'm trying to get the div to resize when the window is resized. With the following code i get "this.fullScreen is not a function" If i remove the window resize it works fine but obviously doesn't resize with the window. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

```
var PE = {};

PE.functions = {
  fullScreen: function fullScreen() {
    var fullScreen = $('.full-screen'),
      navbarHeight = $('.navbar').height(),
      windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      windowWidth = $(window).width();

    fullScreen.css({
      width: windowWidth,
      height: windowHeight - navbarHeight
    });
  },

  fullScreenResize: function screenResize() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        this.fullScreen();
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  PE.functions.fullScreenResize()
});
```

Comment: Is the error literally “this.functionName is not a function”? If not, provide the actual function name referenced, as well as indicate which line of your provided code is in the backtrace for the exception.

Comment: Sorry error is Uncaught TypeError: this.fullScreen is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fullScreenResize`, the call to `this.fullScreen()`, `this` is not necessarily the `PE.functions` object because the callback function passed to `resize` has a different `this`. To remedy, [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callback function to the current `this`:

```
fullScreenResize: function screenResize() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
      this.fullScreen();
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Or replace `this.fullScreen()` with the full object path `PE.functions.fullScreen()`.